# passing default arguments in function implementation

Tags: c

I am defining a function with default parameters.

```
state* construct_state(int final_state=0, int start_state=0)      
{
      //code
}
```

However there is some error

```
nfa.c:16:39: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no default arguments in C.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot provide default arguments in C.